# How can I interact with Kind cluster? context "mycluster" does not exist

Tags: kubernetes

I can list all the clusters

```
kind get clusters

cluster01
fluxcd
kind
medium-cluster
mmana
prodan
```

But when I try to invoke `mmana` cluster

```
kubectl cluster-info --context mmana
error: context "mmana" does not exist
```

How to invoke my cluster?

Answer (score 0):

I found out

kubectl cluster-info --context kind-mmana